# Как в IDEA делать Step Into в конкретный метод?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Допустим, имеется строка `methodOne(methodTwo(methodThree()))`.
Жму **Step Into** во время дебага и попадаю сначала в самый вложенный метод. Как делать более осмысленный переход, скажем, в `methodTwo` или в `methodOne`?

Ставить breakpoint именно в эти методы, или выносить участок `methodTwo(methodThree())` в отдельную переменную - не предлагайте, пожалуйста. Во время "путешествия по коду" каждый раз это делать трудоемко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого в идее есть хоткей shift+f7 так называемый smart step into, это позволит выбрать в какой именно метод в точке останова вам необходимо зайти. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/choosing-a-method-to-step-into.html

Comment: Спасибо) А есть ли какой-то способ добавить эту кнопку на панель инструментов к остальным (в run идти лень, а все хоткеи запомнить трудновато)

Comment: К сожалению вывести это нельзя, на дебаг панели только step into https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debug-tool-window.html#steptoolbar, если вам эта функция нужна и вы будете часто пользоваться ей, хоткей легко запомнится

Comment: @TheSN Вообще-то добавить кнопку можно: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDn5H.png (после этого надо перезапустить debug).